# The new Google Groups interface—where is the pending members' answer to custom question

Tags: google-groups

In Google Groups, if you allow people to request membership, you can have them answer a custom question (in the new Google Groups interface it's called a "New Member Question").  But the old Google Groups page for accepting pending members had a column title "Reason" which displayed the answer.  I do not see any such column on the new interface and can't find anywhere where I might see that information.

Answer (score 1):

The new Google Groups interface has a "Reason" column under **Manage** > **Members** > **Join requests**. I do not know when this was added.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find this column anywhere either. But you could review pending users under old interface (probably only in limited time, until new groups roll out completely). Just type this address:
`https://groups.google.com/group/<your group name>/pending`